# Center images on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few tables next to each other (3 tables in row 1, 3 tables row 2 and 1 table row 3) and when I hover over table cells, some images should show in the center of the screen. This is what it currently looks like (switch to full page):

```js
function imageAppear(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById('lightBox').style.visibility = "visible";
}

function imageDisappear(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById('lightBox').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
.tool2 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.tool2 td {
  width: 1%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
  border-color: black;
}

.tool2 th {
  width: 1%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
  border-color: black;
}

.tool2 .border {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  ;
  border-color: #333;
  text-align: center
}

.tool2 .header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  ;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #000000;
  text-align: center
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 33%; height: 150px; float:left;">
  <table class="tool2" style="width: 90%">
    <tr>
      <th class="header" colspan="5">Table 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border" colspan="2">Invoices</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">E-Mail</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">Sentiment Analysis</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">CRM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border" onmouseover="imageAppear('ocr1')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('ocr1')">OCR<img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/posts/NbYbNrs.png" alt="Ui_OCR" id="ocr1" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);visibility: hidden;" /></td>
      <td class="border" onmouseover="imageAppear('fe1')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('fe1')">Field extract<img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/posts/NbYbNrs.png" alt="UI_FE" id="fe1" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="width:33%; height: 150px;float:left">
  <table class="tool2" style="width: 90%">
    <tr>
      <th class="header" colspan="5">Table 2 </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border" colspan="2">Invoices</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">E-Mail</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">Sentiment Analysis</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">CRM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border" onmouseover="imageAppear('ocr2')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('ocr2')">OCR<img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/posts/NbYbNrs.png" alt="Ui_OCR" id="ocr2" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;" /></td>
      <td class="border" onmouseover="imageAppear('fe2')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('fe2')">Field extract<img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/posts/NbYbNrs.png" alt="UI_FE" id="fe2" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="width:33%; height: 150px; float:left">
  <table class="tool2" style="width: 90%">
    <tr>
      <th class="header" colspan="5">Table 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border" colspan="2">Invoices</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">E-Mail</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">Sentiment Analysis</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">CRM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border" onmouseover="imageAppear('ocr3')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('ocr3')">OCR<img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/posts/NbYbNrs.png" alt="Ui_OCR" id="ocr3" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;" /></td>
      <td class="border" onmouseover="imageAppear('fe3')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('fe3')">Field extract
        <img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/posts/NbYbNrs.png" %} " alt="UI_FE " id="fe3" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden; " /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
          
        <div class="wrapper " style="width:33%; height: 150px;float:left ">
        <table class="tool2 " style="width: 90% ">
          <tr>
        <th class="header " colspan="5 ">Table 4</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td class="border " colspan="2 ">Invoices</td>
        <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">E-Mail</td>
        <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">Sentiment Analysis</td>
        <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">CRM</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('ocr4') " onmouseout="imageDisappear('ocr4') ">OCR<img src="" alt="Ui_OCR " id="ocr4" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left:
          50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden; "/></td>
        <td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('fe4') " onmouseout="imageDisappear('fe4') ">Field extract<img src="" alt="UI_FE " id="fe4" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top:
          50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden; "/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper " style="width:33%; height: 150px;float:left ">
        <table class="tool2 " style="width: 90% ">
          <tr>
        <th class="header " colspan="5 ">Table 5</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td class="border " colspan="2 ">Invoices</td>
        <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">E-Mail</td>
        <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">Sentiment Analysis</td>
        <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">CRM</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('ocr5') " onmouseout="imageDisappear('ocr5') ">OCR<img src="" alt="Ui_OCR " id="ocr5" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left:
          50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden; "/></td>
        <td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('fe5') " onmouseout="imageDisappear('fe5') ">Field extract<img src="" alt="UI_FE " id="fe5 " style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top:
          50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden; "/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper " style="width:33%; height: 150px;float:left ">
        <table class="tool2 " style="width: 90% ">
          <tr>
        <th class="header " colspan="5 ">Table 6</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td class="border " colspan="2 ">Invoices</td>
        <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">E-Mail</td>
        <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">Sentiment Analysis</td>
        <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">CRM</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear( 'ocr6') " onmouseout="imageDisappear( 'ocr6') ">OCR<img src="" alt="Ui_OCR " id="ocr6" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left:
          50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden; "/></td>
        <td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('fe6') " onmouseout="imageDisappear('fe6') ">Field extract<img src="" alt="UI_FE " id="fe6 " style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top:
          50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden; "/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper " style="width:33%; height: 150px;float:left ">
        <table class="tool2 " style="width: 90% ">
          <tr>
        <th class="header " colspan="5 ">Table 7</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td class="border " colspan="2 ">Invoices</td>
        <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">E-Mail</td>
        <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">Sentiment Analysis</td>
        <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">CRM</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear( 'ocr7') " onmouseout="imageDisappear('ocr7') ">OCR<img src="" alt="Ui_OCR " id="ocr7" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left:
          50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden; "/></td>
        <td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('fe7') " onmouseout="imageDisappear('fe7') ">Field extract<img src="" alt="UI_FE " id="fe7 " style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top:
          50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden; "/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper " style="width:33%; height: 150px;float:left; ">
    <table class="tool2 " style="width: 90%; ">
      <tr>
    <th class="header " colspan="5 ">Table 8</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    <td class="border " colspan="2 ">Invoices</td>
    <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">E-Mail</td>
    <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">Sentiment Analysis</td>
    <td class="border " rowspan="2 ">CRM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    <td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('ocr8') " onmouseout="imageDisappear('ocr8') ">OCR<img src="" alt="Ui_OCR " id="ocr8" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden; "/></td>
    <td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('fe8') " onmouseout="imageDisappear('fe8') ">Field extract<img src="" alt="UI_FE " id="fe8 " style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top:
          50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden; "/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
        <div id="lightBox " class="light-box "></div>
```

But I am facing some problems:
1. I can't seem to figure out how to edit the `<img>` style values to position the shown images in the center of the screen, starting at the current scroll position, no matter from which table cell the image is shown.
2. The page is adding so much blank space at the bottom to make room for the images. Is there a fix for this?
3. I use the `lightBox` as an element to grey out the webpage behind the image. The complete page gets greyed out besides the tables themselves, but I can't figure out why that is.

Answer (score 1):

Your inline CSS are not same on 2 `OCR` td tags. That's the reason you are having this issue.

```js
function imageAppear(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById('lightBox').style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0].style.position = "static";
}

function imageDisappear(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById('lightBox').style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0].style.position = "relative";
}
```

```css
.tool2 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.tool2 td {
  width: 1%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
  border-color: black;
}

.tool2 th {
  width: 1%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
  border-color: black;
}

.tool2 .border {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  ;
  border-color: #333;
  text-align: center
}

.tool2 .header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  ;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #000000;
  text-align: center
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 33%; height: 150px; float:left;">
  <table class="tool2" style="width: 90%">
    <tr>
      <th class="header" colspan="5">Table 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border" colspan="2">Invoices</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">E-Mail</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">Sentiment Analysis</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">CRM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border" onmouseover="imageAppear('ocr')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('ocr')">OCR<img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/posts/NbYbNrs.png" alt="Ui_OCR" id="ocr" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;" /></td>
      <td class="border" onmouseover="imageAppear('fe')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('fe')">Field extract<img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/posts/NbYbNrs.png" alt="UI_FE" id="fe" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="width:33%; height: 150px;float:left">
  <table class="tool2" style="width: 90%">
    <tr>
      <th class="header" colspan="5">Table 2 </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border" colspan="2">Invoices</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">E-Mail</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">Sentiment Analysis</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">CRM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border" onmouseover="imageAppear('ocr')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('ocr')">OCR<img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/posts/NbYbNrs.png" alt="Ui_OCR" id="ocr" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;" /></td>
      <td class="border" onmouseover="imageAppear('fe')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('fe')">Field extract<img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/posts/NbYbNrs.png" alt="UI_FE" id="fe" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="width:33%; height: 150px; float:left">
  <table class="tool2" style="width: 90%">
    <tr>
      <th class="header" colspan="5">Table 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border" colspan="2">Invoices</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">E-Mail</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">Sentiment Analysis</td>
      <td class="border" rowspan="2">CRM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border" onmouseover="imageAppear('ocr')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('ocr')">OCR<img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/posts/NbYbNrs.png" alt="Ui_OCR" id="ocr" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;" /></td>
      <td class="border" onmouseover="imageAppear('fe')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('fe')">Field extract
        <img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/posts/NbYbNrs.png" %} " alt="UI_FE " id="fe" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="wrapper " style="width:33%; height: 200px;float:left ">
<table class="tool2 " style="width: 90% ">
  <tr>
<th class="header " colspan="5 ">Table 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="border " colspan="2 ">Invoices</td>
<td class="border " rowspan="2 ">E-Mail</td>
<td class="border " rowspan="2 ">Sentiment Analysis</td>
<td class="border " rowspan="2 ">CRM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('ocr') " onmouseout="imageDisappear( 'ocr') ">OCR<img src="{% static "home/Screenshots/UiPath/InvToExcel.png" %} " alt="Ui_OCR " id="ocr" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;"/></td>
<td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('fe') " onmouseout="imageDisappear( 'fe') ">Field extract<img src="{% static "home/Screenshots/UiPath/InvToExcel_Extract.png" %} " alt="UI_FE " id="fe" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="wrapper " style="width:33%; height: 150px;float:left ">
<table class="tool2 " style="width: 90% ">
  <tr>
<th class="header " colspan="5 ">Table 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="border " colspan="2 ">Invoices</td>
<td class="border " rowspan="2 ">E-Mail</td>
<td class="border " rowspan="2 ">Sentiment Analysis</td>
<td class="border " rowspan="2 ">CRM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('ocr')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('ocr')">OCR<img src="{% static "home/Screenshots/UiPath/InvToExcel.png" %} " alt="Ui_OCR " id="ocr" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;"/></td>
<td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('fe') " onmouseout="imageDisappear('fe')">Field extract<img src="{% static "home/Screenshots/UiPath/InvToExcel_Extract.png" %} " alt="UI_FE" id="fe" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="wrapper " style="width:33%; height: 150px;float:left ">
<table class="tool2 " style="width: 90% ">
  <tr>
<th class="header " colspan="5 ">Table 6</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="border " colspan="2 ">Invoices</td>
<td class="border " rowspan="2 ">E-Mail</td>
<td class="border " rowspan="2 ">Sentiment Analysis</td>
<td class="border " rowspan="2 ">CRM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('ocr')" onmouseout="imageDisappear( 'ocr') ">OCR<img src="{% static "home/Screenshots/UiPath/InvToExcel.png" %} " alt="Ui_OCR " id="ocr" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;"/></td>
<td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('fe')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('fe') ">Field extract<img src="{% static "home/Screenshots/UiPath/InvToExcel_Extract.png" %} " alt="UI_FE " id="fe" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="wrapper " style="width:33%; height: 150px;float:left ">
<table class="tool2 " style="width: 90% ">
  <tr>
<th class="header " colspan="5 ">Table 7</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="border " colspan="2 ">Invoices</td>
<td class="border " rowspan="2 ">E-Mail</td>
<td class="border " rowspan="2 ">Sentiment Analysis</td>
<td class="border " rowspan="2 ">CRM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear( 'ocr') " onmouseout="imageDisappear( 'ocr') ">OCR<img src="{% static "home/Screenshots/UiPath/InvToExcel.png" %} " alt="Ui_OCR " id="ocr" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;"/></td>
<td class="border " onmouseover="imageAppear('fe') " onmouseout="imageDisappear( 'fe') ">Field extract<img src="{% static "home/Screenshots/UiPath/InvToExcel_Extract.png" %} " alt="UI_FE " id="fe" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="lightBox" class="light-box "></div>
```

By the way, `id` is a unique identifier so don't assign the same `id` on the multiple tags. If  like to assign the same then add as a class instead of `id`

Comment: Thanks first of all. I copied all 3 parts in my project, but the images are not centered there, just in the code snippet somehow? On my page all images are on the left side of the screen.

Comment: Check the style on image tag. It should be this: `style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;"` Secondly, remove the spacing from the `id` attribute in you.

Comment: All styles match. And whitespaces in the id tags are also removed (have the same html as in your answer)

Comment: @Colle Is it works now? As in snippet here, it is working correctly so I hope it works there too.

Comment: Oh my bad I forgot to add the CSS from the wrapper class. I edited it into my OP. This is causing the issue. But I can't just delete the wrapper CSS